# JavaScript/HTML5 Library to achieve Customized Organization Chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts

[image]

I need a JavaScript/HTML5  Library to achieve the following requirement **which nodes in the same level (1 and 2 ) should be positioned in two different locations** [as per another data attribute.]

I look though lot of libraries but coundnt not achieve this , any ideas on directly or indirectly achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:
1. You create two item templates, the first one must have an extra space at the bottom. And Items should be aligned to bottom, so it would create affect that your first item raised inside of row. 
2. You need to create explicit collection of rows and set their minimal height. And then align every item vertically.

In general I consider it is wasting of screen space. You can achieve the same affect by colors, border width, shadows etc without wasting pressures screen space. It looks like you are trying to mimic paper org chart in your application and it is wrong from my perspective.